# Update Validator Plugin Manager for custom implementation

Tags: validation, zend-framework

I have created a few validator elements which extend from the generic `Zend\Validator\<validator>`. My goal is to make them available as was a generic default alias. Let me further explain.

My goal is to have the inclusion in the form to use the same alias notation, such as:

```
    $inputFilterFactory = new InputFilterFactory();
    $inputFilter = $inputFilterFactory->createInputFilter([
        'foo' => [
            'name'       => 'foo',
            'required'   => false,
            'validators' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'NotEmpty',
                ],
                [
                    'name' => 'StringLength',
                    'options' => [
                        'min' => 3,
                        'max' => 5,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
     ]);
```

Here, you can see that the validator `NotEmpty` references `Zend\Validator\NotEmpty`, when I want it to reference `Project\Validator\NotEmpty` and that the validator `StringLength` references `Zend\Validator\StringLength` when I want it to reference `Project\Validator\StringLength`

If you look here: https://github.com/zendframework/zend-validator/blob/master/src/ValidatorPluginManager.php  You'll see that this is where the validators get defined for seeding into the service manager.

**My primary solution would be to create a new ValidatorPluginManager completely and rewire the service manager to use the custom validator plugin manager (I am firm on this because I will eventually have a bunch of extended validators so I'd like to completely rewrite the validator plugin manager**

If that is not available then id like to know whats the next best step, conforming to the same alias as currently shipped with default validators.

Thanks!